# Passing two arrays in a function

Tags: julia

I am trying to work with 2 arrays in a function with a for loop but I do not know the syntax, since there are no examples in the internet. I have written the code without function but I would certainly appreciate if this was transformed to a function. The output is the array price and the array succrate. Thank you in advance.

```
length_of_arrays = 101

lower_limit = 0
steps_per_unit = 1

price1 = 10

succrate1 = 5
succrate2 = 7

price = Array{Float64, 1}(101)
succrate = Array{Float64, 1}(101)

for pr_A = 1:1:length_of_arrays

price[pr_A] = lower_limit + ((pr_A-1) / steps_per_unit)

if price[pr_A] == price1
  succrate[pr_A] = succrate1
else
  succrate[pr_A] = succrate2
end
end
```

Comment: There are many examples in the [official docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/). Have you checked there yet? Also, you are most likely to get a helpful response if you post a minimum working example. Currently, we have no idea what `length_of_arrays`, `steps_per_unit`, `lower_limit`, `price`, `price1`, or `succrate` are.

Comment: All are constants. Except for price and succrate that are arrays.

Answer (score 2):

There is no special syntax for passing in arrays. Just pass them as an argument like anything else. The arrays will be modified in the function (to mark this I have followed a convention of using a final `!` in the name) so there's no need to return them from the function.

```
function calc_prices!(price, succrate, lower_limit, steps_per_unit, price1, succrate1, succrate2)
    for pr_A in eachindex(price)
        price[pr_A] = lower_limit + ((pr_A-1) / steps_per_unit)

        if price[pr_A] == price1
            succrate[pr_A] = succrate1
        else
            succrate[pr_A] = succrate2
        end
    end
end

len_of_arrays = 101
pri = Array{Float64, 1}(len_of_arrays)
succ = Array{Float64, 1}(len_of_arrays)

calc_prices!(pri, succ, 0, 1, 10, 5, 7)

println(pri[10])
println(succ[10])
```

Comment: Thank you. And how do I call this function to find out the 10th element of the arrays price and succrate?

Comment: `modifyarrays!(loa, pr, ll, spu, suc); pr[10]; suc[10]`

Comment: How can I print this? What is the syntax? Thanks again

Comment: Of course. But I am new in programming and there is no similar example with arrays, for loops and functions and printing. I have to see many examples and connect them and I have done so but no result. I did what Borregaard said but no result in Atom. it does not print even if I type    result = modifyarrays!(loa, pr, ll, spu, suc); pr[10]; suc[10]    println(result)

Comment: Here's a deal - I'll update my answer to a working solution if you provide a minimal working example (something that can be copied into the REPL and run), as suggested by Colin's comment on question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007699/passing-two-arrays-in-a-function/47009616?noredirect=1#comment80962332_47007699

Comment: Here what I got so far... (updated in the original question)

Comment: Thank you! You have been really helpful. I wish I could vote

Comment: Why didn't you use eachindex(price, succrate)? Why is succrate omitted? if you have multiple arrays of different dimensions and nested for loops what would you do?

Comment: Because they have the same length. eachindex(price, succrate) is fine too. If you have nested for loops you'd do `for i in eachindex(price), j in eachindex(succrate)`

Comment: That is ok. Thanks a lot. Now I am facing a different problem. I have multidimensional arrays and I am using eachindex but the result is zero. There are for loops and multidimensional arrays of different size. Should I use cartesian index / range?

Comment: Try to ask that as a new question, providing an MWE, and preferably linking the parts of the manual that you've read in order to understand it yourself.

Comment: I found out that eachindex in multidimensional arrays produces a bounds error, so I used for i in 1:101 (fixed bounds) to get it through and it did get through.

Answer (score 0):

I used for i in 1:length_of_array, since eachindex in nested for loops produced a bounds error

```
function modifyarrays!(length_of_arrays, price, lower_limit, steps_per_unit, succrate)
for pr_A in 1:101

    price[pr_A] = lower_limit + ((pr_A-1) / steps_per_unit)

  for d in 1:20
    if price[pr_A] == price1
        succrate[pr_A, d] = succrate1
    else
        succrate[pr_A, d] = succrate2
    end
  end
end

end

length_of_arrays = 101

lower_limit = 0
steps_per_unit = 1

price1 = 10

succrate1 = 5
succrate2 = 7

price = Array{Float64, 1}(101)
succrate = Array{Float64, 2}(101,20)


modifyarrays!(101, price, 0, 1, succrate)

println(succrate[11, 2])
```

I would be happy to get an answer on how eachindex could have worked or about cartesian index.

In addition, how do I call succrate from the modifyarrays! function into another function?

Comment: And now the question is? How do I call modifyarrays! function and more specifically the succrate argument in another function?